# Fill a container with content using React.JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a container element, which is also a React component, with a specific height. I also have an API that returns blocks of contents of variable length, based on the requested ID.

```
<Contents/>
```

I want to request a new block of content from the API until the container is overflowing.

My code works, but it rerenders all content blocks and adds one in each render, until the container is full. This seems like a bad approach.

```
class Contents extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            numElements: 0
        };
    }

    render() {
        const elements = [];
        for(let i = 0; i < this.state.numElements; i++) {
            elements.push(this._getElementContents(i));
        }

        return(<div id="contents">
            {elements.map(element => element)}
        </div>);
    }


    componentDidMount() {
        // start the 'filling loop'
        this._addElement();
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        // keep adding stuff until container is full
        if(document.getElementById('contents').clientHeight < window.outerHeight - 400) {
            this._addElement();
        }
    }

    _addElement() {
        // setState will cause render() to be called again
        this.setState({numElements: this.state.numElements + 1});
    }

    _getElementContents(i) {
        // simplified, gets stuff from API:
        let contents = api_response;
        return(<Element key={i} body={contents} />);
    }
}
```

How can I append elements to the container until it is filled, without re-adding, re-querying the API and re-rendering existing elements on each loop?

Answer (score 3):

I can't see how you are calling your API or under what condition. From my understanding you should do two things.

Keep `elements` array into the `state` object and push new elements whenever they arrive.

Use the `shouldComponentUpdate` instead of `componentDidUpdate` with the same exactly condition to judge when you  have to request more elements from your API.

Eventually draw the `state.elements`. Whenever you receive a new one you just use the local elements you previously got to redraw the component instead of making all API calls all over again

Comment: In this._getElementContents() I make an Ajax call using jQuery, but I let that out to simplify the example. I will try your suggestions, thanks!

Comment: I cannot use `shouldComponentUpdate` to add more elements to the `state.elements` array, because you cannot use `setState` in `shouldComponentUpdate`. Any other ideas?

Comment: `shouldComponentUpdate: function(nextProps, nextState) { return document.getElementById('contents').clientHeight < window.outerHeight - 400; }`

then since this is true the update will happen, thus `componentDidUpdate` will be triggered only then so you can safely change `componentDidUpdate` to remove the `if` statement like so:

`componentDidUpdate : function(){ this._addElement(); }`

Answer (score 1):

Because this.setState() triggers a re-render, like dimitrisk said, you should put logic in shouldComponentUpdate to only render once you have everything ready to go to the DOM.

You should look into Dynamic Children in React. It helps React do reconciliation  when re-rendering http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#dynamic-children
http://revelry.co/dynamic-child-components-with-react/